# SMTP email using Powershell... No exception error but email never sends

Tags: email, office365, smtpclient

I am trying to create a simple email notification using an office365 email account and Smtp mail in a Powershell script. Using the code below, I am not getting any error or exception but the email is never received.  I am not sure where to look.  There are other scripts (in Java) that use the same email address to send from and port without issue.

```
function sendMail ($message)
{
    "Sending Email"

    #SMTP server name
    $smtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"

    #Creating a Mail object
    $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

    $emailPassword = "xyz123"
    $emailCredential = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("X@X.com", $emailPassword)

    #Creating SMTP server object
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
    $smtp.Port = 587
    
    $smtp.EnableSSl = $true
    $smtp.Credentials = $emailCredential
    $smtp.DeliveryMethod = "Network" 
    
    #Email structure
    $msg.From = "X@X.com"
    $msg.To.add("Y@x.com")
    $msg.subject = "Alert Triggered"
    $msg.body = $message 

    $smtp.timeout = 60000 
    
    #Sending email
    $smtp.Send($msg)

    "Email Sent"

};


try {
    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 
    Sendmail("Alert Triggered")
    "Done" 
    exit
}
catch {
    echo $error[0]
}
```

Comment: If you're confident this completes without error, then the logical conclusion is that your logic is fine, and the server itself is failing to send it for some reason (such as appearing too similar to spam) or that the server did send it, but it ended up getting caught by some other spam filter or sent to the user's junk mail filter.

Comment: The server limits the number of emails that can be sent that way.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev  what do you mean? it never sent an email on the first try.

Comment: Then you need to run the code under the debugger attached. If that doesn't shed the light I'd suggest checking what Fiddler says in that case.